# How to get a clicked accordion tab to be opened at the top of your screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Zurb's Foundation framework for creating a responsive web-app. One thing I'm stuck, but I really wish to implement is when a user clicks an accordion tab (example: [Zurb's site](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html)), I want the to be opened (& clicked) tab to be 'scrolled' to the top of the screen and then be openend, instead of when clicked somewhere on your screen, it opens from that point.

Simply said: When an accordion tab is clicked, the page should scroll so the clicked element is positioned at the top of the page (with +20px offset).

Thanks!

Comment: i use child.scrollIntoView() and then container.scrollTop-=20 right after

Comment: A quick google to 'child.scrollIntoView()' made me think you are talking about something of .aspx or .net programming. Are these Javascript scripts..?

Comment: it's a method of html Element objects in the JS dom, for example, document.body... when i google "scrollIntoView" i get an mdn lucky hit. ScrollIntoView() works well, but it puts it too close to the top, which is why the 20px scroll up just after makes it work better. when done together, you never actually see the two different scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Zurb before, but you need to modify the function that adds/removes the `active` class. See the code here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js

I recommend changing line 33 from this:

```
target.addClass(settings.active_class);
```

to this

```
$('html, body')
    .animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 2000)
    .promise()
    .done(function() {
        target.addClass(settings.active_class);
    });
```

But I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will actually work D:

It should take 2 seconds (look for the `2000`) to scroll, and when that's done, add the class like before

Comment: Let me clarify this is /partially/ working. I've added '.top - 100' to the offset, to create a real offset. However, sometimes it doesn't get positioned correctly. I can't find characteristics of when it does and when it does not gets positioned correctly. Not positioned correctly, means the tab gets positioned 'above' the viewport.. Will post when found the problem! Thanks, incredibly already! :)

Comment: I think the issue was an animation script that animates the opening/collapse of the tab panels. I've added a delay(*) equal to the time of the scroll duration. It doesn't positions to top, anymore. However, the scrolling and opening/collapse effect seem a little more spontaneous now, which is even better! =D Thanks!